# Array problem, missing boolean cutouts

Tags: modeling

I am having a problem with an array. Array of mesh-cubes, 2 dimensional 8x8, used two cubes to cut out areas with boolean differences.
All of the duplicate instances have the cutouts but the original does not.
Exorted stl file is same.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the cubes used to cut the holes in the cube duplicated in the array fixed the problem in the primary cube without altering the cutouts of the primary cube or the duplicate instances with the same cutouts. -Fixed